# Will my wall stand up to fairly heavy pine planking on the inside?

Tags: walls, mounting, load-bearing

I have just purchased yellow pine tongue-and-groove lumber for the interior of my home.  As I moved the wood in 16' lengths into to house to acclimate, I noticed the extreme heaviness of each piece.  They are about 7/8" in thickness.  My total accent wall is 9' by 14'. The wall is an outside wall (brick exterior).  Does anyone have any advice on whether the total weight I am adding to this wall could be a potential hazard?

Thanks!

Comment: Brick wall "veneers" are typically freestanding--they don't bear on the wood framing. They often rest on a ledge built into the foundation. They are, however, anchored to the framed wall with straps or other devices to prevent tipping.

Answer (score 3):

So, not shiplap. And, oh now you care. Nope, no problem at all, the inside wall's studs will handle it all fine. You'd only have a possible issue if you went outside of the wall studs' plane, like with loaded shelving that pulled laterally on the wall. With fasteners it'll all probably weigh about 413-lbs. It'll be great for decades to come.

[image: Shiplap vs. Tongue & Groove]

Comment: Thanks SOOO much for your help and clarification.  I actually mis-spoke in my original comment.  The wood siding is going on the inside of the house, the outside of the house is made of brick.  So my concern is about adding all that weight to the interior wall studs.  I don't want to create a situation where the interior weight is too stressful on the structure and begins to compromise the integrity of that wall.

Comment: I was just prodding you on the wood edging, but now you know. Inside was what I wasn't quite sure about. I'll correct my answer.